How to display the image swatch of a product attribute in the woocommerce archive pages under the title and on the single product page under the title
In woocommerce, I would like to show product attributes on the shop page and single product page under the product titles. The product attribute is "intensiteit"
This is what I have for now:
add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'display_attributes_after_product_loop_title', 15);
function display_attributes_after_product_loop_title(){
    global $product;

    $output = array(); // Initializing
    $a = ("sterkte: ");

    

    // Intensity
    if( $intensiteit = $product->get_attribute('pa_intensiteit') )
    {
        // Save the value in the array
        $output[] = $intensiteit ; 
    }

    // Output
    if( sizeof($output) > 0 ){
        // Display product attributes coma separated values (you can change the separator by something else below).
        echo '<span class="sterkte">' . $a; echo implode( ', ', $output) . '</span>';
      
    
    }
}

This is what I have now:

This is what I'm expecting. I only need to get the green round(image swatch) to be shown also

